# Can I specify partition in "reboot" or any similar commands?

Tags: partition, osx, reboot

I like to make scripts for everything that takes a bit of time, and when I have to reboot to another partition, I press the reboot button and then hold alt (⌥) and then I have to choose partition. I'd like to be able to just run a script, leave the computer for 30 seconds and then have it booted up on the other partition.

One solution I think is setting a default partition, at least I can do this in the System Preferences so there's very likely a solution to it in the terminal, and then reboot normally. However, I would rather not do this, because I want my default partition to stay.

Comment: I don't know how the reboot command can be made to do this, but the usual route is to run the bless command first.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yeah, that involves setting the default partition, right?

Comment: They thought of that! Give bless the --nextonly option to change the boot volume for just the next boot.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I just found that reading the man page. Thanks however for reminding me of that command.